# split string array and store key value pair in list or dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

How to split product array string using , and save key value pair in dictionary or list. String in cookie is:

```
cookieValue ="12&150&pid=1,name=abc,size=2gm    Sachet,price=50,image=Pouch.jpg,quantity=1&pid=2,name=xyz,size=200gm   Packet,price=50,image=small.jpg,quantity=2"
```

products array is as below:

```
[0] "12"
[1] "150"
[2] "pid=1,name=abc,size=2gm Sachet,price=50,image=Pouch.jpg,quantity=1"
[3] "pid=2,name=xyz,size=200gm    Packet,price=50,image=small.jpg,quantity=2"
```

Code for processing cookie:

```
if(HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Cart"]!= null)
{
  var cookieValue = Request.Cookies["Cart"].Value;

  string[] products = cookieValue.Split('&');

  var len = products.Length;                             
  for(int x=2;x<=len;x++)
  {
     string s1 = products[x];
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the _Value_ part of the _Key_ = 12?

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = s1.Split(',');

Comment: i just wanted to take 2nd and 3rd array value string and split it using (,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

You cannot use dictionary as there are duplicate keys. But you can use List of KeyValuePairs.

```
        var products = cookieValue.Split('&');

        var keyValueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            var sequence = product.Split(',').ToList();
            var isValidSequence = sequence.Count > 1;
            if (!isValidSequence) continue;

            sequence.ForEach(s =>
                    keyValueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s.Split('=')[0], s.Split('=')[1]))
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, splitting the input string at the & produces an array of 4 elements, so assuming that the first half of this array represents something that you want to skip and the second half is the Product itself with the *pid* field to use as the Key for the KeyValuePair structure you can transform that string in a `Dictionary<int, Product>` in this way

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Size {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public string Image {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get;set;}
}

Dictionary<int, Product> dicProducts = new Dictionary<int, Product>();
string[] products = cookieValue.Split('&');
var len = products.Length;                             
int half = len / 2;
for(int x=half;x<len;x++)
{
    string[] productData = products[x].Split(',');
    Product p = new Product()
    {

        ID = Convert.ToInt32(productData[0]);
        Name = productData[1];
        Size = productData[2];
        Price = Convert.ToDecimal(productData[3]);
        Image = productData[4];
        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(productData[5]);
    }
    dicProducts.Add(p.ID, p);
}
```

This is a very simple code to traverse the input data and I have added no kind of check on the input data to not overcomplicate the example. In a real world application scenario you should add a lot of checks. For example, the input data should be divisible exactly by two, the strings found in the product part should be checked for their completemess and validity.

Comment: first half is not key

Comment: pid=1,name=abc,size=2gm Sachet,price=50,image=Pouch.jpg,quantity=1

Comment: So the key is pid?

Comment: in this case pid is key and 1 is value like this i want to store